# Flask to get the table table values where rows are dynamically inserted

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have below html, file

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data_container">
    <form  method="POST" action="{{ url_for('grades_input') }}">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr><th>Name</th><th>Job</th><th>Grade</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="job"></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="grades" name="grade">
                        {% for grade in grade_select %}
                        <option value="{{ grade.type }}">{{ grade.type }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
    <button id="submit_rows">Submit</button>
    <button id="add_rows">+</button>
</div>
```

with the `+` button it will dynamically copy the rows with it's attributes to your page.
Now in my flask jinja query gives me grades from the grade table and when it's `GET` method I could see it is properly populated in my selections drop down.

```
@app.route('/grade_select')
def grade_select():
    conn = getMysqlConnection()
    cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute("select distinct grades from `grade` where `student_id` = session[id];")
    grades_select = cursor.fetchall() 
    # return jsonify(transportation_type) --> [{ 'type' : 'A' } ... ]
    return render_template('Input_form_page.html', grades_select=grades_select)
```

So, my question is when it is the `POST` method, how to fetch each input value from the HTML? Let's just say, user press 2 times, so two new rows are added to the form and the user filled in 2 sets of name, job, and grade. So, then how to access these 2 sets of rows, values from the table? is this kind of list added to the corresponding names which then loop thru ?

```
@app.route('/grade_select', methods=[POST])
    def grade_select_post():
        redirect(url_for('grade_select'))
        for input in request.form:
           print(input)
        return jsonify('hi')
```